# Does anybody knows if OpenCTI can match phones right to left?

Tags: opencti

Does anybody knows if Open CTI is able to match phones from right-to-left, not just in usual order? Our business has several local offices all over the world and all have phones stored in different format.

We like that OpenCTI functinality, that matches the incoming call to the existing SFDC record and gives a quick hyperlink to open it. But there's one shortcoming here.

As far as I know, now Salesforce by default searches phone number symbol by symbol, starting from left to right, so, for example 2 phone numbers (0034)12345678 and (0)12345678 won't match, because starting from different prefixes.

However, if Open CTI would start that search from the end, instead of start (right-to-left matching) these 2 numbers would show a match. So, for example if  we have 003412345678 written down in our phone field on account level, and our Avaya server identifies the incoming call as +3412345678 it would be matched all the same.

It doesn't help to re-format all the existing phones in SFDC base, because phone providers from different countries just like to send caller phone data in different format, some transmit international prefixes, some don't. So, solving this'd help much to make all phones recognizable and matchable to existing SFDC records.